# Method Local Inner classes program

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am just learning Java concepts.
Can anyone let me know why i am not able to run this program?

```
package innerClasses;

public class Test {
    int i=10;
    static int j=20;
    public void m1() {
        int k=30;
        final int m=40;

        class Inner {
            public void m2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Test.Inner in = t.new Inner();
        t.m1();
    }

}
```

Can anyone let me know why i am not able to run this program?

Comment: why don't you tell us? do you get an error message? does it come during compilation/run-time? what does it say?

Comment: you can't declare a class within a method, let alone assume that 'll be a valid inner class

Comment: Getting Compile time error saying-Multiple marker at this line, Test.Inner cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: the reason for that is in my second comment

Comment: I recommend reading through this. the problem is you are trying to create a local class, and trying to use it as an inner class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: @Stultuske "you can't declare a class within a method". Actually, [you can](https://ideone.com/K011jp).

Comment: @Michael yes, I was wrong about that. I was confused by the 'inner class' mention in the title, and the way the OP tried to use the class

Answer (score 2):

The most basic reason is because of scope. In order to do

```
Test.Inner in = t.new Inner();
```

`Inner` must be defined in `Test`, but it is instead defined in `m1` scope.

Comment: But as per the concept of "Method Local Inner classes" we can declare a class within a method.

Comment: The issue is still scoping. Your main declaration is trying to access a nested class, but you are defining a method local class. If your intent is to actually access the method local class, then you can only do it in the context of `m1`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Inner` is declared inside the method `m1()`, what makes it not available outside this method.

Your code has to look like the following to be able to run, although it will not print anything...

```
public class Test {

    int i=10;
    static int j=20;

    public void m1() {
        int k=30;
        final int m=40;
    }

    class Inner {
        public void m2() {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Test.Inner in = t.new Inner();
        t.m1();
    }

}
```

Replacing `t.m1();` by `in.m2();` will output 10.

**EDIT**

In case you have to create the inner class inside the method, make it like

```
public class Test {

    int i=10;
    static int j=20;

    public void m1() {

        int k=30;
        final int m=40;

        class Inner {
            public void m2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        // this is what makes it run
        Inner myInner = new Inner();
        myInner.m2();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1();
    }

}
```

to compile and run.

IMHO this is not a good way to go...

Comment: actually i am using concept of "Method local inner classes" and according to this I have to define Inner class within m1().

Comment: @AnkitJain Please see my edit and answer me the question *why do you want to declare a class inside a method of another class?*

Answer (score 0):

A method inner class is only visible to that method only so you can't use this at any other location.

for using this class you have to declare it outside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile it as the scope of Inner class is the m1 method.
If you want to be able to create instances of Inner class you can define it directly inside the Test:

```
public class Test {
    int i=10;
    static int j=20;

    public void m1() {
        int k=30;
        final int m=40;
    }

    // On the Test class level 
    class Inner {
        public void m2() {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Test.Inner in = t.new Inner();
        t.m1();
        in.m2(); // prints 10
    }
}
```

Another feature provided by Java is to use anonymous classes. It can be created by implementation of some Interface:

```
// Define an interface to be able to implement it inside the method
interface Inner {
    void m2();
}

public class Test {
    int i=10;
    static int j=20;

    public void m1() {
        int k=30;
        final int m=40;

        // Implement interface and call method on it
        // Functional style: 
        ((Inner) () -> System.out.println(i)).m2();

        // Legacy style:
        new Inner() {
            @Override
            public void m2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }.m2();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1(); // prints 10 twice
    }
}
```

or extending some class:

```
// A class we going to extend
class Inner {
    void m2() {
        System.out.println(11);
    }
}

public class Test {
    int i=10;
    static int j=20;

    public void m1() {
        int k=30;
        final int m=40;

        // Extend inner class and call method on it
        new Inner() {
            void m2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }.m2();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1(); // prints 10, not 11
    }
}
```

So the best way for you depends on what code design do you want to get finally.

Answer (score 0):

Your `class Inner` is what the JLS calls a [Local Class (14.3. Local Class Declarations)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3).

The [scope of a Local Class is defined as (6.3. Scope of a Declaration)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block (§14.2) is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.
>
> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a switch block statement group (§14.11) is the rest of the immediately enclosing switch block statement group, including its own class declaration.

In your case it is declared in a block, which is the body of your method. So the scope where your class is visible is the rest of this method body.

As the type `Inner` is not visible in `main()`, you cannot use it there. You could create instances of it and use them within `m1()`, though.

Answer (score 0):

The very basic reason for compile time error is "Scope".
As per your code, class Inner is defined inside method `m1` (this class is called `Local class/method local class`),so if you observe the scope of method variable, its within the declared method only and we cannot access any method variable outside that method and this is reason, the scope of `class Inner` is limited to the `m1` method
so if you want to instantiate `class Inner` and invoke its methods then you must do it in `m1` method (in code , you are trying to create class Inner object outside method `m1`, which is not possible) hence the code would be

```
public class Test {
int i = 10;
    static int j = 20;
    public void m1() {
        int k = 30;
        final int m = 40;
        class Inner {
            public void m2() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        Inner in = new Inner();
        in.m2();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1();
    }
}
```

some more info , the local classes can be used when any repeated functionality is required inside a method (as nested methods are not allowed in java, so we can create inner class) and off course if we are not interested to create class level method  for example

```
class Outer {
    public void cal() { 
        class Inner {
            public void sum(int x, int y) {
                System.out.println("sum : "+(x+y));
            }
        }
        Inner i= new Inner();
        i.sum(10, 20); //sum is repeatdly needed in between code
        i.sum(100, 200);
        i.sum(1000, 2000);
        i.sum(10000, 20000);
    }
}
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().cal();
    }
}
```